# curl simulation for facebook publishing

Tags: iphone, facebook, curl

To publish photos on the Facebook need to perform:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'source=@file.png' \
     -F 'message=Caption for the photo' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
```

example from developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo

How to create the same POST request in the iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

I like the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library a lot. Without that library, you would have to use NSURLConnection, which is a lot more low level.

Comment: Is it possible to do with NSURLConnection?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, as I said. If you google for "nsurlconnection post" the first result is here on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071788/iphone-sending-post-with-nsurlconnection