# How can I do a simple curl call with post field in objective c?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, curl

to be more specific, this is what I need to do in objective c,
what is the equivalent for this?

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"api.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "a message to the site");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"GET" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: Application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`.

`NSURLRequest`: you can init it with an **URL**, set the **POST** variables as **HTTP** Body, be sure the set the head correctly (eg: google for an example).

Then load the `NSURLRequest` with an `NSURLConnection`, even asynchronous as synchronous as you want.

See [Append data to a POST NSURLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest) and [iPhone sending POST with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071788/iphone-sending-post-with-nsurlconnection)

Comment: i tried this for over a week now, im still getting an empty string in the post on the server side